# error C2664 on bst comparison template

Tags: c++, set, binary-search-tree

This error:

> error C2664: 'Set::Set(int (__cdecl *)(ElemType,ElemType))'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl
>   *)(CorrectionT &,CorrectionT &)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(ElemType,ElemType)'

is the result of implementing this comparison function as part of a BST based SET class,

```
int compareCorr(struct CorrectionT &a, struct CorrectionT &b)
{
    if (a.editDistance < b.editDistance) return -1;
    else if (a.editDistance == b.editDistance) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

Class Set

```
Set(int (*cmpFn)(ElemType, ElemType) = OperatorCmp);
```

and the use of the comparison function in Set is for add

```
template <typename ElemType>
void Set<ElemType>::add(ElemType element) {
    bst.add(element);
}
```

And add in the bst class
restating header file

```
BST(int (*cmpFn)(ElemType one, ElemType two) = OperatorCmp);
```

and the function add

```
template <typename ElemType>
bool BST<ElemType>::add(ElemType data) {
        bool createdNewNode = false;
        recAddNode(root, data, createdNewNode);
        if (createdNewNode) timestamp++;
        return createdNewNode;
}

template <typename ElemType>
bool BST<ElemType>::recAddNode(nodeT * & t, ElemType & data,
                               bool & createdNewNode) {
        if (t == NULL) {
                t = new nodeT;
                t->data = data;
                t->bf = BST_IN_BALANCE;
                t->left = t->right = NULL;
                createdNewNode = true;
                numNodes++;
                return true;
        }
        int sign = cmpFn(data, t->data);
        if (sign == 0) {
                t->data = data;
                createdNewNode = false;
                return false;
        }
        int bfDelta = 0;
        if (sign < 0) {
                if (recAddNode(t->left, data, createdNewNode)) {
                        bfDelta = -1;   /* left subtree is higher */
                }
        } else {
                if (recAddNode(t->right, data, createdNewNode)) {
                        bfDelta = +1;   /* right subtree is higher */
                }
        }
        updateBF(t, bfDelta);
        return (bfDelta != 0 && t->bf != BST_IN_BALANCE);
}
```

Any idea what is going on here - what is the problem with the comparison function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `compareCorr` is `int(Lexicon::CorrectionT&, Lexicon::CorrectionT &)`.  Its parameters are references.

The type of `cmpFn`, the parameter of the constructor, is `int(*)(ElemType, ElemType)`.  Its parameters are objects (not references).

The types must match.  Assuming that `ElemType` is `Lexicon::CorrectionT`, you must either change the function pointer type to have reference parameter types or change the comparer type to have object paramter types.  (If you go the reference route, they should both probably use const references, since a comparer should not mutate objects.)

Alternatively, you can do what the STL does, and make the comparer a part of the  type, allowing usage of arbitrary function objects for comparison.  Then, the comparer just needs to have parameters of types compatible with the types of the objects being compared (i.e., things don't need to match exactly).

Comment: that sounds good, but my level of experience makes it difficult to understand what you are saying. You lost me at "either change the function pointer type to have reference parameter types or change the comparer type to have object paramter types."

Comment: Your `compareCorr` has parameters of type `Lexicon::CorrectionT&`.  The ampersand means the parameter is a _reference_.  Your `cmpFn` is a pointer to a function that takes two parameters of type `ElemType` (note that there's no ampersand:  the arguments are passed by value, not by reference).  These must match:  in short, the ampersands must be removed from the parameters `compareCorr`, or they must be added to the parameters of `cmpFn` (if you take this latter approach, you should make both pairs `const&`, not just `&`, since your comparer should not mutate the objects being compared).